# Rails running two different version of ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using rubymine and when I go to the terminal and type ruby -v I get ruby 2.5.5, which matches my gemfile.

But when I go to start the server I get this error message:
Your Ruby version is 2.4.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.5

Why is my development server running a different version of ruby and how to I get them to match?

Comment: What server? Is it on a different machine or VM? Do you have more than one version of Ruby installed?

Comment: I did have 2 versions of ruby installed.  I went to setting and changed my SDK over and now it is working.  Thanks!